# getIntent in broadcast receiver undefined android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-pendingintent

In my app I have a pending intent that when broadcasts when its requirements are met this is listened for by a broadcast receiver. This broadcast receiver then does what I want it to do however I need to add extras from one activity to the other and I am using `intent.putExtra` to do this. 
`

However, within my Receiver class `getIntent()` method is undefined. How does it work when using it with pending intents as it has worked with all my other intents.

This is my targetdistance.class: (sets up broadcast and pending intent)

```
package com.example.drivetext;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class targetdistance extends Activity {

double finalc1;
double finalc2;
int finalsd;
String finalmessage;
String finalnumber;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.target);

    LocationManager locationManager;
    locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    String provider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String contactNo;
    contactNo = intent.getStringExtra("PhoneNumber");
    finalnumber = contactNo;
    String message;
    message = intent.getStringExtra("TextMessage");
    finalmessage = message;
    double coord1 = 0;
    coord1 = intent.getDoubleExtra("Coordinate1", coord1);
    finalc1 = coord1;
    double coord2 = 0;
    coord2 = intent.getDoubleExtra("Coordinate2", coord2);
    finalc2 = coord2;
    int seldis = 0;
    seldis = intent.getIntExtra("SelectedDistance", seldis);
    finalsd = seldis;

    LocationManager lm;
    double lat = finalc1;
    double long1 = finalc2;    //Defining Latitude & Longitude
    float radius=finalsd;                         //Defining Radius

           lm=(LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
           Intent i= new Intent();
           i.putExtra("PhoneNumber", contactNo);
           i.putExtra("TextMessage", message);
           PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), -1, i, 0);              
           lm.addProximityAlert(lat, long1, radius, -1, pi);
       }   
}
```

This is my Receiver.class (the broadcast receiver)

```
package com.example.drivetext;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;

public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

String finalnumber;
String finalmessage;

 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) { 

     Intent intent4 = getIntent();
     String contactNo;
     contactNo = intent4.getStringExtra("PhoneNumber");
     finalnumber = contactNo;
     String message;
     message = intent4.getStringExtra("TextMessage");
     finalmessage = message;

  String k=LocationManager.KEY_PROXIMITY_ENTERING;
 // Key for determining whether user is leaving or entering 

  boolean state=arg1.getBooleanExtra(k, false);
  //Gives whether the user is entering or leaving in boolean form

  if(state){
   // Call the Notification Service or anything else that you would like to do here
   SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
   String sendTo = finalnumber;
   String myMessage = finalmessage;
   smsManager.sendTextMessage(sendTo, null, myMessage, null, null);
   }

}
}
```

Comment: Where do you send BroadCast?

Comment: PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), -1, i, 0);

Comment: where is `sendBroadcast(intent);`??

Answer (score 6):

> However, within my Receiver class getIntent() method is undefined.

`getIntent()` is method of Activity class. You can use `arg1` which is a param @  `public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {`

```
String contactNo;
contactNo = arg1.getStringExtra("PhoneNumber");
```

You also need to send the broadcast `sendBroadcast(intent);`

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#sendBroadcast(android.content.Intent)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#sendBroadcast%28android.content.Intent%29)